# How to convert boost path type to string?

Tags: c++, boost, path

Hello I currently have a program that gets a full path of a file's location and is put into a variable that is the type of: boost::filesystem2::path

I have looked up how to do this and have found that using:

```
string result1 = boost::filesystem::basename (myPath)
```

will convert the path to string BUT it only converts the file name (e.g. if the path is "C:\name\bobsAwesomeWordDoc.docx" it just returns "bobsAwesomeWordDoc").

I have found the following on how to convert the entire path to string,
but I don't know how to implement it in my program. I have tried multiple ways but I am getting conversion errors.

> const std::string& string( ): This routine returns a copy of the string with which the path was initialized, with formatting per the path grammar rules.

(found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-boostfs/index.html))

I have tried:

```
string result1 = string& (myPath);
```

and a few other variations.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You just need to call `myPath.string()`.

Comment: Are there guarantues that string returns utf8 encoded path on all platforms?

Comment: @SergeyShambir: Unfortunately not. One can explicitly use `u8string()`, but that doesn't help where `string()` is used automatically.

Answer (score 20):

I believe you need to do a little more than just convert the path to a string - you should first obtain the canonical version of the path - an absolute path with no symbolic-link elements - and convert *that* into a string:

```
boost::filesystem::canonical(myPath).string();
```

P.S. - I've been programming with Boost for ages and I couldn't easily find this info in the docs.

---

**Update (Oct 2017)**

Documentation: [boost::filesystem::canonical](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical).

But note that as of C++17 there is [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), with [canonical](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) and a lot more.

Comment: The accepted answer is a much simpler alternative (and it works)

Comment: canonical is deprecated in newer versions of Boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html

Comment: @BrianJack huh, how is it deprecated? Sry, cannot find any official note... see also 1.60 reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical

Comment: @MarcoAlka See the linked table http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html and note the second line: class path canonize()   Function removed  - that means it was once in the library but no longer--the definition of deprecated.

Comment: @BrianJack  It is the `canonize` that is deprecated, per your second link, but [`canonical`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical) doesn't seem to be (per your first link, for 1_48 V3).  Now in C++17 we have [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) of course

Answer (score 3):

This worked in wxWidgets: (I know I should just use the wx utilities
but it is a test)

```
void WxWidgetsBoostTestFrame::OnTestBtnClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    boost::filesystem::path currentPath;
    currentPath = boost::filesystem::current_path();
    std::string curDirString;
    curDirString = boost::filesystem::canonical(currentPath).string();
    wxString mystring(curDirString.c_str(), wxConvUTF8);
    wxMessageBox(mystring); // output:  C:/Users\client\Desktop...      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `myPath.generic_string()` will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I had to do

```
boost::filesystem::absolute(path).string()
```

to get it to work, as:

```
path.string()
```

kept returning a relative path.

Answer (score -1):

Do this

`path.c_str();`

You should be fine.